# How do I store array of integers in vertica database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vertica

Currently I'm working on vertica database. 
I'm facing problem while storing array of integers in one column. I imported data values through csv.

I used the following code to create table.

```
CREATE TABLE testing_table_1 (email varchar,name varchar,gen int,yob int,ct int,cy int,a varchar(65000),b varchar(65000),c varchar(65000));
```

I imported data with the following code.

```
COPY testing_table_1 from '/home/naresh/Desktop/bigfile.csv' parser fcsvparser();
```

My sample CSV format looks like the below.

```
ghchnu@tly.org.cn | Donald Garcia | 2 | 2003 | 21947 | 91 | 241,127,225,68,162 | 4,84,63,69,15 | 32,44,15,31
rlmx@jyqewy.biz   | Charles Brown | 2 | 2012 | 22218 | 45 | 127,156,186,136,242 | 49,69,14,80,95,1 | 39,36,38,40,20
```

7th,8th and 9th columns are storing in the format of a string.
But what I want is, I want them to be stored in an array of integers format.

Because of the string format I am unable to perform combination of integers operation using 'IN' query.

I don't to want to use flex-table format in vertica. 
Give suggestions other than flex-table format.

Please give me a possible solution for the above problem.

Please correct me if I am doing any mistake.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The data type of those columns is `VarChar`, of course it's storing strings. And afaik Vertica doesn't support arrays.

Comment: It is storing array of integers in flex table format. Please check the following link https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/FlexTables/ComplexDataTypesForfavroparser.htm#Arrays

Answer (score 2):

Vertica is a real, SQL based, relational database.

And those actually do not have rows with a variable number of columns - which is what using arrays would boil down to.
What you need to do is to make, out of this:

```
[...] 91 | 241,127,225,68,162 | 4,84,63,69,15 | 32,44,15,31
```

This:

```
[...] 91 | 1 | 241 |   4 |  32
[...] 91 | 2 | 127 |  84 |  44
[...] 91 | 3 | 225 |  63 |  15
[...] 91 | 4 |  68 |  69 |  31
[...] 91 | 5 | 162 |  15 |(null)
```

Check out the SPLIT_PART() function; you might want to run it with 1,2,3,4 and finally 5 as the third parameter, and use that very number as the key that you see in the second displayed column above. To get the resulting column as integers, cast the strings that come out of the SPLIT_PART() function to integers.

Good luck - 
Marco

Comment: Yea, this is the right approach. The only alternative - if you **really** want to store "an array of integer in a single column" -  would be to convert each array element to 64 bits integer and store all of them into a VARBINARY.